# How to share click event for Switch and its container without recreation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a clickable `Row` containing a `Switch` to replicate a settings option. How can I ensure that the `Switch` gets checked/unchecked whenever I click the `Row` rather than specifically just the `Switch` control?

```
@Composable
fun ComposableSettingSimpleMode() {
    val isChecked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable(onClick = {})) {
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.colour_blind))
        Switch(checked = isChecked.value, onCheckedChange = {
            isChecked.value = it
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ComposableSettingSimpleMode() {
    // this variable will disable the action to change the state
    // without greyed out the component.
    var yourEnableLogic = false 
    var isChecked by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val onChange by rememberUpdatedState { checked: Boolean ->
        if (yourEnableLogic) { // if is enable, we can change the state
            isChecked = checked
        }
    }
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable(onClick = { onChange(!isChecked) })
    ) {
        Text(text = "Bla")
        Switch(checked = isChecked, onCheckedChange = onChange)
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I disable the `Switch` without making it look greyed out?

Comment: I edited my answer to do what you want.

Comment: After testing it, I feel it looks better when the `Switch` is enabled. How can the ripple effect be triggered when I click the `Switch`?